# Story where ocean advances from one basin to another through extreme tides?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Colonists in a sleep ship are redirected to a different world than what they signed up for and some emergency is cited as an excuse, though they suspect this was planned all along because the cargo contains supplies aimed at cold weather destination.

They start setting things up in the tropics, and are surprised when the entire ocean shifts to innundate the land they were building on.  They realize that this is due to tides.

They figure out that they need to live at the high lattitudes to avoid this issue.  And indeed, the destination was a scam.

Comment: I recognize that this likely isn't the answer, but it sounds a lot like the Lavalight world from the World of Tiers series.

Comment: Someone else is looking for it, too: https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/2005669-short-story-colonization-ship-crashes-on-planet-where-tides-are-very-str

Comment: Not the same: I recall they moved to cold latitudes.  I don’t see how migrating crop care would work if the sea drowns everything, and the time scale is wrong.